# Alias for a data type

Tags: haskell

I want to define a data type `Polar` to perform calculations using polar coordinates:

```
data Polar = Polar { distance :: Double, angle :: Double }
```

and have functions like `rotate`, `sum` and so on.

Then, I would like to have a "synonym class" (or just alias) like
`TwsTwa` (true wind speed and true wind angle) like

```
data TwsTwa = TwsTwa { tws :: Double, twa :: Double }
```

without having to redefine the functions.

Is the following, using a class, the best solution for that?
Is it the shorter one? Please note I'm referring to the way `TwsTwa` is defined, not to how difficult is to write the general code for `Polar`.
What alternatives are there?

```
-- .................................................
-- .................................................
class PolarFamily tPolar where
  distanceP :: tPolar -> Double
  angleP :: tPolar -> Double
  toMe :: Polar -> tPolar

  rotate :: tPolar -> Double -> tPolar
  rotate pol ang =
     toMe $ Polar {distance=distanceP pol, angle=(angleP pol) + ang}

  sumP :: tPolar -> tPolar -> tPolar
  sumP p1 p2 =
     toMe $ Polar {distance=(distanceP p1)+(distanceP p2), 
            angle=(angleP p1)+(angleP p2) } -- caution: wrong calculation

-- .................................................
-- .................................................
data Polar = Polar { distance :: Double, angle :: Double }

instance PolarFamily Polar where
  distanceP = distance
  angleP = angle
  toMe p = p
```

TwsTwa is defined then like this:

```
-- .................................................
-- .................................................
data TwsTwa = TwsTwa { tws :: Double, twa :: Double }

instance PolarFamily TwsTwa where
  distanceP = tws
  angleP = twa
  toMe Polar{ distance=d, angle=a} = TwsTwa {tws=d, twa=a}
```

Comment: If you feel like putting a strain on yourself you might make them newtype wrappers on tuples and have the typeclasses just return them unwrapped. Then you have a very easy and simple access to lens functions on tuples but hey that's kinda hacky and can get out of hand.

Comment: @Welperooni I'm sorry for not fully understanding you. Never used lenses. If this approach is simpler, then you could write a short example. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A type alias is typically constructed with the **`type` keyword**. For example:

```
type TwsTwa = Polar
```

Now you can use `TwsTwa` everywhere in the code, and the compiler will translate this to `Polar` behind the curtains.

But now we of course still have not defined `tws :: TwsTwa -> Double` and `twa :: TwsTwa -> Double`, we can do so by:

```
tws :: TwsTwa -> Double
tws = distance

twa :: TwsTwa -> Double
twa = angle
```

And we probably want to declare a *bi-directional* pattern-synonym as well, such that we can work with a `TwsTwa` "data constructor" (although technically speaking, we only defined a synonym, not a new one):

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

pattern TwsTwa :: Double -> Double -> Polar
pattern TwsTwa { tws, twa } = Polar twa tws
-- can use record syntax
-- including field accesses, record updates, and record construction
```

Although personally I think defining new constructors, and patterns is a bit overkill. Simply using a type synonym should be sufficient.

Type synonyms are used for the several reasons:

- to reduce the complexity of a certain type. For example:

  ```
  type MightError a = Either String a
  type TwoList a = ([a], [a])
  ```
- to use a type that can later change, for example:

  ```
  type Time = Int
  ```

  if we later change our mind, we can set `Time` to `Integer`, and then all functions with `Time` are updated automatically.

Comment: Great! Didn't know <- for this: pattern TwsTwa { tws, twa } <- Polar twa tws

Answer (score 2):

This is what I meant, not the best, but an interesting option

```
import Control.Lens

newtype Polar = Polar { unPolar :: (Double,Double) } deriving Show
newtype TwsTwa = TwsTwa { unTws :: (Double,Double) } deriving Show

class ToTup a where
  -- You could make them accept any type instead of just Double but idk
  iTup :: Iso' (Double,Double) a
  unPol :: a -> (Double,Double)

  rotate :: Double -> a -> a
  rotate ang = under iTup (\(x,y) -> (y,x+ang)) 

  sumP :: a -> a -> a
  sumP p1 = under iTup (\(x,y) -> unPol p1 & (\(x1,y1) -> (x1+x,y1+y))) 

instance ToTup Polar where
  iTup = iso Polar unPolar 
  unPol = unPolar

instance ToTup TwsTwa where
  iTup = iso TwsTwa unTws
  unPol = unTws
```

But hey, it protects you from accidentally passing in a wrong type, whereas a type synonym is just for convenience.